# Viewpager content not showing in fragment using ScrollView but Scroll bar showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager

My problem is different. With the below xml layouts, I am showing viewpager pages fluently in activity. There is no problem in scroll view and also contents shows. But when I am using the same code in fragment in navigation drawer, then `scroll bar` showing but contents not showing. Blank page shows.

I used `android:fillViewport="true"`. but no result. below is the image.I also used fixed height for `scrollview`. but no result.

[image]

This is Main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is Child layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is Main java

```
public class SwipeNav extends Fragment {
    private MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_swipe, container, false);
            myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
            return rootView;
        }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

This is MyPagerAdapter Class

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context= context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        ArrayList<String> listItem = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SqliteDatabase.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM ARATRIKA", new String[]{});
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }
        }
        Object[] mStringArray = listItem.toArray();
        Fragment fragment = new AFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(AFragment.ARG_OBJECT, (String)mStringArray[i]);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        ////
        ArrayList<String> listItem = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SqliteDatabase.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM ARATRIKA", new String[]{});
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            listItem.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME")));
        }
       return listItem.size();
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        //return tabTitleArray[position];
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code of your  `MyPagerAdapter`  class

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod I added MyPagerAdapter. Plz check

Comment: have u checked your "listitem.size()" whether is returning zero or correct count.

Comment: @Goutham  there is no problem regarding the code when using in activity.  In fragment "listitem.size()" shows correct count. not all pages shows blank. where page data exceeds, then that particular page becomes blank. other pages shows ok.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain _exactly_ what the issue is. "not all pages shows blank." – Which pages are blank? Which are not? "where page data exceeds, then that particular page becomes blank." – What do you mean by "page data"? Exceeds what?

Comment: check `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated`. Try inflating and return fragment layout in `onCreateView` and initialize the UI in `onViewCreated`

Comment: @Mike M. Where scrollView needs, at that field, the page becomes blank. where scrollview not necessary, at that field, viewpager page data that comes from database shows.

Comment: @Amol G I applied your suggestion, but no solution.

Comment: so, debug in `MyPagerAdapter ` check `getCount` and `getItem` what they are returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. android:hardwareAccelerated in the Manifest was 'true'. I changed to 'false'

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
 </manifest>
```

Anyway Thanks to You All for helping me to solve the problem.